# Is "Are we supposed to deliver an extempore or a prepared speech?" correct?

Tags: grammar

Is "Are we supposed to deliver an extempore or a prepared speech?" correct? As "extempore" is an adjective, does it describe "speech" here?

Comment: Not all adjectives can be used prenominally. If you're unsure about 'extempore', check in a dictionary. Lexico might just help.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Does it sound right to you?

Comment: Does Lexico's having virtually the exact same sentence (first part) not have any relevance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Latin prepositional phrase: *ex tempore*

Literally translated, the unassimilated Latin prepositional phrase *ex tempore* means “out of (the) time”. This has often been run together as a single lexeme by dropping the phrase’s spaces, just like many other, more native prepositional phrases have: *nowadays, today, asleep, hereafter*.

Originally it was used adverbially, but your example uses it as an attributive adjective, meaning one falling before its noun rather than predicatively after a copula. First though the adverbial usage, which here floats to the end:

1. I delivered the sermon ***ex tempore***.
2. I delivered an ***extempore*** sermon.

The OED has this for the adverbial sense of *extempore*:

> ## A. *adv*
>
> 1. At the moment, without premeditation or preparation; at first sight; off-hand. Now usually with reference to speech, composition, or musical performance. ***to speak extempore*** in present use often merely means to speak without notes, or without reading from manuscript. ***to pray extempore*** is opposed to using a set form of prayer.

And they have this for the adjectival use:

> ## B. *adj.*
>
> 1. Arising out of the moment; casual, occasional; sudden, unprepared for. Now only of personal actions (cf. A. 2).
> 2. a. Of a discourse, etc.: Composed, spoken, performed, or acted at the moment, without premeditation or preparation. Now usually understood to mean: Without the assistance of notes, or without reading.

You may use it with or without the space.

### An English alternative: *extemporaneous*

Using unassimilated Latin phrases in English text can come across as needlessly erudite and off-putting to many readers. As an alternative, we have a slightly more naturalized version we can use there as well:

3. I delivered the sermon **extemporaneously**.
4. I delivered an **extemporaneous** sermon.

This version no longer suffers the same stigma as speaking *ex tempore* may. It’s still just an ***off-the-cuff*** speech.

#### Clipped alternative: *extemp*

Another common and more casual equivalent is to “clip” it down to just ***extemp*** as a sort of *ad hoc* abbreviation for the longer term.

In [high school and college **forensics competitions**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Individual_events_(speech)#Extemporaneous_speaking), the Extemporaneous Speaking category is all about delivering ***extemp*  speeches**.

When referring to these talks, the informal “clipped” abbreviation ***extemp*** is often used for such by academics.

Comment: So is my question grammatically correct?

Comment: @Brobdingnagian What do you imagine to be faulty with its syntax or morphology?

Comment: I believe "Are we supposed to deliver an ____..." expects a noun, but I have used an adjective. I am not sure if "extempore" describes "speech" in this case.

Comment: @Brobdingnagian That verb used transitively as you have here doesn’t expect merely a noun as its direct object, but rather an entire **noun phrase**, which is a  specific type of syntactic constituent. Consider how the sentence *“Are we supposed to deliver an unrehearsed speech?”* similarly has an adjective following the article. Adjectives are integral portions of noun phrases. Therefore the syntax is permissible. The tone is a bit fancy, though: see my edit for an Englisher alternative.

Comment: ♦ Yeah, thanks for the correction. Is my question correct?

Comment: @Brobdingnagian Its grammatical structure is impeccable. In [high school and college **forensics competitions**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Individual_events_(speech)#Extemporaneous_speaking), the Extemporaneous Speaking category is all about delivering ***extemp*  speeches**, which is the normal informal “clipped” abbreviation used for such by academics.

Comment: Okay, so "extempore" does describe "speech" in my question. Thanks.